# entity framework many-to-many relationship deleting objects and creating references

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, entity

so im using angularJS to pass a dealer object to my controller. Each dealer object has a virtual ICollection. I use HTML multiselect to add contact objects to the contact collection in Dealer then I pass the whole dealer into my C# controller.

This is the code for the controller

```
        public HttpResponseMessage PostDealer(Dealer dealer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var contacts = dealer.contacts;

            db.Dealers.Add(dealer);

            if (dealer.contacts != null)
            {

                foreach (var contact in dealer.contacts)
                {
                    db.Contacts.Attach(contact);
                }
            }


            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, dealer);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = dealer.Id }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

this is how the relationship is set up

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>().HasMany(u => u.contacts)
                    .WithMany(d => d.dealers)
                    .Map(m =>
                        {
                            m.ToTable("ContactMap");
                            m.MapLeftKey("DealerId");
                            m.MapRightKey("Contact_Id");
                        });
```

What happens when I do this is every contact object gets delete from my api/contacts, and is instead replace with a reference to a the Contact in the Dealer object. This is bad because I want to be able to display and edit the contacts from a ContactView page.

#### EDIT

This is what i mean about refrences, here is an example part of the Json..

```
    [
   {
      "$id":"1",
      "dealers":[
     {
        "$id":"2",
        "dealerg":null,
        "contacts":[
           {
    [OMITED OBJECT DETAILS.........]
      "Dealer_Id":null
   },
   {
      "$ref":"3"
   },
   {
      "$ref":"4"
   },
   {
      "$ref":"5"
   }
]
```

#### EDIT

If i change the flent api mapping to

```
           modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>().HasMany(u => u.contacts)
                .WithMany(##removed this piece of code##)
                .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.ToTable("ContactMap");
                        m.MapLeftKey("DealerId");
                        m.MapRightKey("Contact_Id");
                    });
```

I dont get this error however when I create a new contact and associated with a dealer. It will add the dealer to the contacts dealer list... but it wont add the contact to the dealers contact list